# Progress bar is invisible at api>=21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Next progress bar shows whit progress drawable on black square if device api is less than 21, but only black square if device api is >=21

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progress"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:background="@android:color/black"
  android:visibility="visible" />
```

In my styles I have

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>
```

where   `<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFFFF</color>`

Comment: Remove  `android:background="@android:color/black"` from `ProgressBar`.

Comment: @Piyush if i remove background from progress bar and wrap progress bar with frameLayout with black background I have exatly same result

Comment: Yarh Its working fine in api level 23 i have just try this xml you define above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with genymtion emulator, on real devices progress bar is visible on any device